# Gatsby-ssr and React context crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am having a problem where it seems that using gatsby-ssr and react context seem to be making my builds fail.
I get these errors - and have found the problem to be the gatsby ssr file.  By removing this the builds work ? Using Gatsby, Contentful.

```
const React = require("react")
const GlobalContextProvider = require('./src/context/GlobalContext')
exports.wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <GlobalContextProvider>
      {element}
    </GlobalContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Here is the error message

```
Building static HTML failed for path 


  WebpackError: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment   for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

  - build-html.js:110 doBuildPages
    [slut]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/build-html.js:110:24

  - build-html.js:124 async buildHTML
    [slut]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/build-html.js:124:3

  - build.js:200 async build
    [slut]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/build.js:200:5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have exported the GlobalContext in the same way of the code example you are attaching the value in the "exports" object so you must extract from it.

Here 2 examples of export:

Export Literal

```
// file1.js
module.exports = 'Hello world';

// file2.js
var msg = require('./file1.js');

console.log(msg); // Hello world
```

Exports object

```
// file1.js
exports.globalContext = 'Hello world';

// file2.js
var context = require('./file1.js');

console.log(context.globalContext); // Hello world
```